# Regex allow digits and a single dot

Tags: regex

What would be the regex to allow digits *and* a dot? Regarding this `\D` only allows digits, but it doesn't allow a dot, I need it to allow digits and **one** dot this is refer as a float value I need to be valid when doing a `keyup` function in jQuery, but all I need is the regex that only allows what I need it to allow.

This will be in the native of JavaScript `replace` function to remove non-digits and other symbols (except a dot).

Cheers.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you want to allow `1` and `1.2`:

```
(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )
```

If you want to allow `1`, `1.2` and `.1`:

```
(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )|(?<=^| )\.\d+(?=$| )
```

If you want to only allow `1.2` (only floats):

```
(?<=^| )\d+\.\d+(?=$| )
```

`\d` allows digits (while `\D` allows anything *but* digits).

`(?<=^| )` checks that the number is preceded by either a space or the beginning of the string. `(?=$| )` makes sure the string is followed by a space or the end of the string. This makes sure the number isn't part of another number or in the middle of words or anything.

**Edit**: added more options, improved the regexes by adding lookahead- and behinds for making sure the numbers are standalone (i.e. aren't in the middle of words or other numbers.

Comment: That regular expression will report a match on pretty much anything. For example, in .NET the result of `Regex.Replace("xyzzy", @"\d*(\.\d+)?", "!");` will be `!x!y!z!z!y!`. I'm pretty sure the results in JavaScript will be the same. Since everything's optional, the regex will match at every position.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, good call. I edited the answer with improved regexes.

Comment: @[Harpyon] Is there something missing? I get the message "Invalid group": /(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )|(?<=^| )\.\d+(?=$|)/

Comment: Lookbehinds aren't supported by JavaScript apparently.

Answer (score 26):

```
\d*\.\d*
```

**Explanation:**

\d* - any number of digits

\. - a dot

\d* - more digits.

This will match `123.456`, `.123`, `123.`, but not `123`

If you want the dot to be optional, in most languages (don't know about jquery) you can use

```
\d*\.?\d*
```

Comment: `\D` is any character **except** digits. `\d` is what you mean.

Comment: `\D` is the inverse of "match a digit"-- it will match anything but a digit!

Comment: Thank you, @Francisc and @Platinum. I fixed it now. The reason for the mistake is that I copied the `\D` from the original question. I know in Python `\d` means "digit" and `\D` means "anything but a digit", but I thought that if the OP mentioned `\D` then it must be different in jQuery. According to your comments, apparently my first thought was correct and I should have stuck to it :)

Comment: Getting invalid escape sequence in C#. Any help plz

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
boxValue = boxValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"");
```

This Regular Expression will allow only digits and dots in the value of text box.

Comment: this will allow multiple dots, and question is allow only one dot

Answer (score 3):

My try is combined solution.

```
string = string.replace(',', '.').replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "").replace(/\./, "x").replace(/\./g, "").replace(/x/, ".");
string = Math.round( parseFloat(string) * 100) / 100;
```

First line solution from here: [regex replacing multiple periods in floating number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343751/regex-replacing-multiple-periods-in-floating-number) . It replaces comma "," with dot "." ; Replaces first comma with x; Removes all dots and replaces x back to dot.

Second line cleans numbers after dot.

Comment: Thanks. After searching since 2 Hours, I got this answer. And, this is fitting perfectly in my set of requirements (only numeric digits along with one dot). Thanks Once Again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression

```
/^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test()
```