# Regexp only one dot and digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I faced some problems with regex;
I want to leave only valid numbers in a string, people might enter:

1. `11.2.2`
2. `abd11,asd11`

and so on,

```
str = .replace(/[^[0-9]{1,2}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$]/g, '');
```

So I need to allow only digits and one dot from anything the user has entered;

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570820/regex-allow-digits-and-a-single-dot) however doesn't work when I try to put it in:

```
str.replace(/(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )|(?<=^| )\.\d+(?=$| )/,'');
```

It gives me a JS error. Please help me to understand what am I doing wrong.

p.s: thank You all guys for helping me, i found solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343751/regex-replacing-multiple-periods-in-floating-number), so i think thread may be closed.

Comment: Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds such as `(?<=^| )`.

Comment: What should happen with `abd11` - should it be removed entirely or become `abd`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex matching numbers and decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921058/regex-matching-numbers-and-decimals)

Comment: @TimPietzcker: or even just 11?

Comment: From the second expression I see you were trying to remove all floating point numbers from the string ?

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: idealy, "abd11,asd11" must got 1111, but if it will got at least 11, that would be good.

Comment: I think you should provide an example text - before and after - with all relevant cases that should or should not be replaced.

Comment: the idea is to left only digits and one single dot (first): i.e: 123dfs3d.123d.341dde will be equal: 1233.123341

Comment: Oh, so you want to take an entire string like `jkhsdfu23987sdfiuh39.98sd98h.8f987l987sdf` and turn it into `2398739.98988987l987`?

Comment: I have checked the solution. But problem is that it doesn't solves problem with 2 numbers after dot.

Answer (score 1):

use regex as

```
\d*[0-9]\.\d*[0-9]
```

Comment: str = str.replace(/[^\d*[0-9]\.\d*[0-9]]/g, ''); allows 11.11.1

Comment: @ailmcm please check once again : its correct even if u r in doubt verify it at http://regexpal.com/

Comment: How can this be updated to allow for a leading negative sign? e.g. `-1.222`

Answer (score 0):

You must use quotes. Like this:

```
str.replace("/(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )|(?<=^| )\.\d+(?=$| )/",'');
```

Comment: Lookbehind in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/(?: |^)\d*\.?\d+(?: |$)/
```

this will match:

```
12
12.34
.34
```