# Regex allow only 0-9 and the - character, and dot (.)

Tags: c#, regex

I Need a regex to validate `0-9` and allow `.` and `-` characters.

Following is working for `0-9` and `.` characters:

```
Regex invalidCharsRegex = new Regex(@"^*[0-9\.]+$");
```

Comment: `bool _result - Regex.Ismatch("YourString", @"^[0-9\-.]+$")`

Comment: You can find answer here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570820/regex-allow-digits-and-a-single-dot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regex is weird...

```
Regex invalidCharsRegex = new Regex(@"^*[0-9\.]+$");
```

Remove the first asterisk, it's not doing anything good.

And to allow `-` characters, you simply add it to the character class. Also, you don't need to escape the dot in a character class:

```
Regex invalidCharsRegex = new Regex(@"^[0-9.-]+$");
```

If you're trying to validate a number, this regex will have to be revised, because the regex will accept `----` or `.....`. Something a bit like this for integer/floating numbers:

```
Regex invalidCharsRegex = new Regex(@"^\-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex invalidCharsRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )|(?<=^| )\.\d+(?=$| )");
```

This will allow numbers like 1, 1.2, .1 etc