# Accept only number and one dot in js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code which is not working:

```
function isWH(ele)
{
  var r=/\D$/i; // important: prevent space sa password
  if(r.test(ele.value))
  {
    alert("Please check your format");
    ele.value="";
    ele.focus();
  }
}


<input type="text" name="hei" class="textarea" value="<?php echo $hei?>"         onkeyup="isWH(this)" placeholder="e.g. 163"  onKeyDown="CountLeft(this.form.hei,this.form,5);" onKeyUp="CountLeft(this.form.hei,this.form,5);" />
```

Comment: accept only numbers and one dot not working.

Comment: Can you explain a little better your problem?

Comment: the input text box should only accept numbers and one dot for example 1.123 or 12 like that .. in my code it only accept whole number.

Comment: see : -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570820/regex-allow-digits-and-a-single-dot

Comment: Why is this tagged with php?, I mean sure, you're using php to echo a value, but the issue / question has nothing to do with php - I would also strongly recommend reading [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Epodax because this could possibly be done with using php

Answer (score 3):

Try following regex

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#hei').keypress(function(event) 
    {
        var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode

        if (
            (charCode != 45 || $(this).val().indexOf('-') != -1) &&      // “-” CHECK MINUS, AND ONLY ONE.
            (charCode != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&      // “.” CHECK DOT, AND ONLY ONE.
            (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="hei" id="hei" class="textarea" value="<?php echo $hei ?>" 
placeholder="e.g. 163" onKeyDown="CountLeft(this.form.hei,this.form,5);" 
onKeyUp="CountLeft(this.form.hei,this.form,5);" />
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20pajtnh/)**

Comment: its not working .sorry newbie

function isWH(ele)
 {
 var r=/^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/; // 
 if(r.test(ele.value))
 {
 alert("Please check your format");
 ele.value="";
 ele.focus();
 }
 }

Comment: this is because you are calling two functions `onkeyup` in wrong way

Comment: @안젤라 try updated answer