# Change input type of textbox

Tags: javascript

I am using a script for my textbox to make sure the user can enter only numbers instead of text.

Here is my textbox:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="tb1" name="tb1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

And here is my javascript:

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
     return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want to upgrade my JavaScript. I want that the textbox accepts a input with a dot `.` (only 1 dot), like `11.5`

What do I need to change in my script so it will be accept the dot and limit this to one?

Comment: here is the reference.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5570912/3164682

Comment: You can validate input with REGEX like : /^\d*\.?\d*$/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<input type="text" id="txtCheck" onkeypress="AllowDecimalNumbersOnly(this, event)" />

 function AllowDecimalNumbersOnly(Id, Evt) {
            Id.value = Id.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
            if ((Evt.which != 46 || Id.value.indexOf('.') != -1) && (Evt.which < 48 || Evt.which > 57)) {
                Evt.preventDefault();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript :

```
<script>
var isHav=false;
function isNumber(evt) {
   evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
   if(charCode == 46){  
      if(isHav==true){
         return false;
      }else{
         isHav=true;
         return true;
      }
   }

   if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
   } 
      return true;
   }
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<input type="text" value="" id="tb1" name="tb1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

Comment: This will only allows user to input ***.*** to one time.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use this..

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /^[0-9.,]+$/;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="tb1" name="tb1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

Comment: You should read question properly. He wants only one dot (.) allowing in textbox

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below code:

you need to change your function onkeypress event by adding **this** parameter
just like below:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="tb1" name="tb1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)" />
```

and change your function as below:

```
function isNumber(evt, element) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if ((charCode != 46 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&      // “.” CHECK DOT, AND ONLY ONE.
            (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

You can check below running code:

```js
function isNumber(evt, element) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode

        if ((charCode != 46 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&      // “.” CHECK DOT, AND ONLY ONE.
            (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="tb1" name="tb1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use type="number" attribute if it meet with your requirement

```
<input type="text" value="" id="tb1" name="tb1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" type="number" />
```

Or Use This

```
function isNumber(evt)
{
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
   if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
     && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
      return false;

   return true;
}
```

Comment: This is an accurate script and allow only decimal or int value. I don't know why have u voted down this answer.