# Input allow numbers and single comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an input field in which I want to allow only number and 1 comma. How could I make it accept only single comma?

```
$("#my-field").on("keyup", checkKey);

function checkKey() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, "");
}
```

Comment: write a regular expression to match on comma?

Comment: Don't do this. It is user unfriendly. Colour things, or put messages, but don't make the keyboard disfunctional.

Comment: You can check this post! -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570820/regex-allow-digits-and-a-single-dot

Comment: You should be more specific about the required format to match against.

Answer (score 10):

You could do it like this:

```js
function checkKey() {
    var clean = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, "")
                           .replace(/(,.*?),(.*,)?/, "$1");
    // don't move cursor to end if no change
    if (clean !== this.value) this.value = clean;
}

// demo
document.querySelector('input').oninput = checkKey;
```

```html
<input>
```

This will remove all repeated commas, and everything between them. That is not an issue, since you press one key at a time.

#### Remarks

This blocking way of input validation is user unfriendly. It is better to colour things, or put messages, than to make the keyboard disfunctional.

Consider using the `<input type="number">` element, which has number validation built in.

The `input` event is often more useful for checking for changes in the `input` than `keyup`, since changes can also be made via mouse actions and the context menu.

If you want to allow dot instead of comma, then change every `,` with `\.` in the regular expressions, as `.` has a special meaning in regular expressions, and must be escaped to be taken as a literal character.

Comment: would have liked to see this with a pattern validation instead